# how to get user info in Forms Authentication Across Applications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have an application on my main domain user can login to this domain and will be authenticate across all sub domain i use form authentication to do this and its works fine.

but i do not know how to retrieve users some information on sub domain .
to do this i must to have user ID or Somethings like this to use it to retrieve user information by sql server.

how can i handle this scenario and transfer some useful information to use it on sub domains to retrieve user information?

my application is on mvc4 razor and .net 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user can authenticate across all of your subdomains, and you are leveraging Forms Authentication, you can simply get the username in the subdomains the same way you can get it in the main domain:

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
```

Comment: What is the part the concerns you? Having the username in the authentication cookie? If so, the cookie is encoded using the machine key and is no different than getting the cookie from the same domain. Concern that the subdomain can view the cookie, then you can prevent that: <forms domain="mydomain.com">. Please let me know if there is another issue that makes you concern.

Comment: thanks for your answer i concern about rub authenticate cookie and put on another machine and use it

Comment: Without the machinekey, the auth token cannot be decoded. Since the machine key is on the server, I would not worry about that. NOTE: If the main domain and subdomain are on separate machines, make sure that the machinekey is the same for both. Otherwise, the subdomain will not be able to decode the machine key.